# React router v6 nested routes can't go up one level using navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Target**

I'm using react router v6.

I have a parent route with a static header with a back button that when I click it needs to go one path above, exp. `/shop/1/item/create` to `/shop/1/item`, when i click the back button i call the function `navigate` from `useNavigate()`

**example**

[image: example]

Red is the root page, yellow is where the static header is and green is content that i want to change

**Problem**

When i call `navigate` regardless of using "." or ".." or "./" the page never change correctly, it either redirects from `/shop/1/items/create` to `/shop` or to `/shop/1`

the only way of redirecting correctly is using -1 but it causes the problem that if someone copy's the URL when going back they get redirected to whatever page they were before pasting the URL.

**Code**

```js
    const ShopPage = () => {
    
        const [ state, setState ] = React.useState<IShopPageState>({ shop: { name: "" }, isInvalid: false })
        const { id } = useParams()
        const navigate = useNavigate()
        
        return (
            <div id="shop-page">
                <Card>
                    <div id="shop-page-header">
                        <Icon canHover onClick={() => navigate("./")} icon="BiArrowBack"/>
                        <Title text={state.shop ? state.shop.name : ""}/>
                    </div>
                </Card>
                <div id="shop-page-content">
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/*" element={<div onClick={() => navigate('./items')}>wddw</div>}/>
                        <Route path="/items/*" element={<ItemsPage shop={state.shop}/>}/>
                        <Route path="/items/create" element={<ItemPage/>}/>
                    </Routes>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Here is the code of the yellow part with only the important stuff, the header is static and always visible and where the back button is.
I believe this code is enough to understand, the green part only redirects the url from `/items/` to `/items/create` using `navigate('./create')`

I think a possible solution would be simply copying pasting the header for each page but i find that to be bad practice and it is a last resort solution

Here is a example of the [problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-route-back-prolem-wnys5h)

**EDIT**

As asked here is some extra code showing the problem

App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<Link to="/shop">Shop</Link>} />
        <Route path="shop/*" element={<Shop />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Shop.js

```js
const Shop = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link to="./">Back</Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<Link to="./items">All</Link>} />
        <Route path="items/*" element={<Link to="./create">Item</Link>} />
        <Route path="items/create" element={<>Create</>} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It's difficult to say why the code isn't working as expected when we can't see all the code. What is rendering the `ShopPage` component? Please update post to include a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @DrewReese my code is dispersed in many files that's why I added a link to a working example of the problem, but in that case i will also add the example to the question

Comment: Using `<Link to="..">Back</Link>` seems to work for me in your CSB.

Comment: @DrewReese for me it's returning to the first page `/`, don't forget my problem is that I want to go one path above `/shop/items/create` to `/shop/items/` for example

Comment: Is the codesandbox an accurate representation of your code? The `".."` only removes a single path segment *within* the `Routes` component rendering it. If you want to do this from a level deeper then you need another `Routes` and another `Link` or `navigate` function navigating to `".."` to "remove" the nested segment. Does this make sense? I'll work on a demo forked from your sandbox.

Comment: Yes and has the exact same behavior, in both `..` returns to root of the parent Routes, and when using other like `../` it also has the same behavior. EDIT: just saw your edit, i'm having trouble warping my mind around about what you said, I will wait for the fork and see if i understand better

Comment: Check this [CSB fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-nested-routes-cant-go-up-one-level-using-navigate-l5h3ue). Note that each "back" link only goes back to the path of the `Routes` component rendering it.

Comment: Ok, now i better understand, but this brings the problem i mentioned in the question, to have the back button work for each level in the url it would require me to copy past the button for each level instead of having one global button that would relatively go back one level in the url. I guess my only solution is to manually edit the url and remove the last level. Thx for the great help

Comment: Yes, exactly. Each `Routes` component would need a link/button to navigate back to ***it***.  What is the issue doing exactly that?

Comment: So in what im working on i have a tag routes with multiple items url `/items` show all items `/items/:id`, show single item `/items/create` create item, what i would like to do is to use the navigate button to go back and jump from `/items/:id` to `/items` and all this without having to re render and copy paste the button like the layout i showed in the image, this way i only need to render the green part, that is why it would be good to have an easy way to simply go one path above in the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245953/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-pekira).

Answer (score -2):

if you are using a nested route then better to use

```
<Route path="/" >
  <Route index element={<Items/>} />
  <Route path="item:id" element={<Item/>} />
</Route>
```

Comment: This does not answer the posted question, nor does it explain *why* it would be better to use a particular method.

Answer (score -2):

You can see a simple hint in the code below for React Router v6

```js
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>React Router</h1>
            <nav>
              <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
              <Link to="/user">User</Link>
            </nav>

            <Routes>
              <Route index element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="user/:Id" element={<User />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Hi, i don't really understand how this helps, i need a way to relatively go up one level in the url path, this code is all static. have you had a look at the example link i added?